While doing KML/KMZ in QGIS, I cannot create labels in Google Earth
I produce a label using the data in the attribute table in the project I open in QGIS. All labels are visible in the program, but when I transfer it as KML, it only transfers polygon data. It does not transfer tags. I searched for other similar questions in the forum, but I still couldn't solve them.



Use the field 'Name' to export labels to kml.

To display labels for a polygon layer, e.g.:

Install the KML Tools plugin:

Use the KML Tools plugin Export KMZ processing tool:

Select a field to use as the "Name/Label field" and then tick the "Use hidden points to display polygon labels" parameter:

Export your layer to a KMZ and then open in Google Earth to see your labels displayed:


Thanks. You helped. So, is it possible to show the created labels on a different layer in Google Earth or QGIS?

As commented by Mapperz:

Use the field 'Name' to export labels to kml.




I duplicated the layer with the data and converted it to dot style. As you said, I gave the name I wanted under the layer name and the labels appeared as I wanted in kml. Now the only problem is to send both geometry data and label data to Google Earth at once :). Thanks
